Identifying a map in a fiber sequence
Let $Q = \Omega^{\infty} \Sigma^{\infty}$ be the stabilization functor. Suppose we have a sequence of maps $Q \mathbb{RP}^{n-1} \to Q \mathbb{RP}^{n} \to QS^n$
and suppose we know that it is a fiber sequence and that the first map is $Q$ applied to the skeletal inclusion $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{RP}^{n}$. Can we conclude from this information that the map $Q \mathbb{RP}^{n} \to QS^n$ is (homotopic to) $Q$ applied to the quotient map?
If $Q$ was replaced by $\Sigma^{\infty}$, then the proof would be easy since the sequence would then also be a cofiber sequence. Now I am not really sure if there is an easy proof (or if it is even true). A first step could be calculating the homotopy classes $\left[Q \mathbb{RP}^{n}, QS^n \right]$, but I don't think this is easy. I may be missing something simple, any help is appreciated!

According to Lemma 2.6 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.6052 there is a weak equivalence from $Q\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$ to the homotopy fibre of $Q$ applied to the quotient map. This doesn't quite answer your question, though.

@MarkGrant right, if we knew the map $Q \mathbb{RP}^{n} \to QS^n$ instead the problem would be easier.

One can prove easily that in homology, the map $QRP^\to QS^n$ induces the "correct map", at least as map of graded algebras, does it help ?

@user43326 thanks for your comment, but I think unfortunately I found that solving my question doesn't solve the larger problem I care about. So I wouldn't recommend anyone to spend time on this (for my sake at least).
